# Delete all records from table in sqlite database

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

I know this is very frequently asked question and i tried everything that i found here. But problem is still there.

Now the problem is i am trying to delete all records from 3 tables with following code but they are not being deleted

```
const char *dbpath = [dbPathString UTF8String];
sqlite3 *sqliteDB;

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &sqliteDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    //Delete all records from attempts
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    NSString *deleteSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"DELETE FROM table1"];

    const char *delete_stmt = [deleteSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqliteDB, delete_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(sqliteDB);
}
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &sqliteDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    //Delete all records from attempts
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    NSString *deleteSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"DELETE FROM table2"];

    const char *delete_stmt = [deleteSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqliteDB, delete_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(sqliteDB);
}
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &sqliteDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    //Delete all records from attempts
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    NSString *deleteSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"DELETE FROM table"];

    const char *delete_stmt = [deleteSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqliteDB, delete_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(sqliteDB);
}
```

I have tried with if conditions like

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqliteDB, delete_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog("All records deleted");
}
```

And this if condition get executed and i do have statement in console log.
I am using Xcode 5.0.
Please help me. Thanx in advance

Comment: How do you know the data is not deleting? Are you deleting the data from the sqlite file which is in the Documents directory?

Comment: Did you cross check for reading the data from xcode after the deletion...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqlite3_prepare_v2` just prepares the statement.
To actually execute it, you must also call [sqlite3_step](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html).

Comment: I really am a dumb. how could i forgot this :P.

Answer (score 0):

Dear friend this is little bit complex coding try to use external class for easy coding

this link will help you

[How to insert update delete in database operation and also save database in document directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953116/how-to-insert-update-delete-in-database-operation-and-also-save-database-in-docu)

for delete record you can use

```
NSString *strDelete = [Database executeScalarQuery:@"DELETE FROM table1"];
```

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Thanks my friend. You have done a really good job. But for now i just needed 1 line code. Thanks mate.